# Watch variables disappear in VSCode when debugging an STM32 project

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, stm32

I've been trying to debug an STM32 project in VSCode. I'm able to start the debugger and add variables to the watch list. However, the moment I run the code, the watch variables disappear. Is there a way to view them in real-time as the code is running? Here is a [short video](https://i.imgur.com/GT3HzSW.mp4) of what happens.

Comment: Have you tried pausing the execution instead of terminating it?

Comment: @Tagli When I pause the code run, it does show again but I was hoping it would be like the Live Variables in Eclipse. STM32 does have the cubeide but it is not the most intuitive of development environments.